# How do I change URL based on form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get some json data based on user input in a form field.

```
$.getJSON("exampleurl.com/name/FormFieldInputHere")
```

So in my HTML I have a standard text field and based on what the user writes in the field, I want to replace FormFieldInputHere with that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to first retrieve the value from the field using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val), then you need to concatenate the strings together.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value of the form field and append it to your string

```
$.getJSON("exampleurl.com/name/" + $('#THEID').val())
```